# getting list for each employee for entire tenure

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table `employee` with the columns `name`, `startdate`, `endate`:

```
name | startdate   |  enddate
--------------------------------
A    | 12/12/2012  |  12/12/2014
B    | 05/08/2006  |  07/11/2009
```

I want result like this:

```
name  |  Year of Employee
-------------------------
A     |     2012
A     |     2013 
A     |     2014 
B     |     2006
B     |     2007
B     |     2008 
B     |     2009
```

Do I have to use a `loop` and/or `cross join` here?

Comment: No.  You could also use a recursive CTE.

Comment: A calendar table will also facilitate this task.

Comment: What join? Is it about SQL?

Comment: Yes it is about sql.

Comment: Can anybody please elaborate on the steps I need to follow? a pseudo-code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE #test(name VARCHAR(10), startdate DATE, enddate DATE)
```

Inserting some sample data

```
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('A', '12/12/2012', '12/12/2014')
                        ,('B', '05/08/2006', '07/11/2009')
```

Using recursive CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT  name, DATEPART(YEAR, startdate) AS yr FROM #test
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  #test.name, yr + 1
        FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN #test ON #test.name = CTE.name
        WHERE yr < DATEPART(YEAR, enddate)
        )
SELECT name, yr AS [Year of Employee]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY name, yr
```

Output

```
name    Year of Employee
A       2012
A       2013
A       2014
B       2006
B       2007
B       2008
B       2009
```

Answer (score 0):

Define and populate a `CalYear` table that delivers this :

```
CalYearStartDate   CalYearEndDate
2005-01-01         2005-12-12
2006-01-01         2006-12-12
2007-01-01         2007-12-12
2008-01-01         2008-12-12
2009-01-01         2009-12-12
2010-01-01         2010-12-12
2011-01-01         2011-12-12
2012-01-01         2012-12-12
2013-01-01         2013-12-12
2014-01-01         2014-12-12
```

Define and populate an `Emp` table that delivers this :

```
EmpName  StartDate   EndDate
A        2012-12-12  2014-12-12
B        2006-05-08  2009-07-11
```

Use this query to retreive results:

```
Select  EmpName,
        CalYearStartDate
From    Emp
Inner
Join    CalYear
on      YEAR(CalYearStartDate)  >= YEAR(Emp.StartDate)
and     YEAR(CalYearEndDate)    <= YEAR(Emp.EndDate)
```

Comment: Recursion is a fine option...but not a good choice for one's first effort.  Once you have this working...you can and should look into recursion...it can do wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #test(name VARCHAR(10), startdate DATE, enddate DATE)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('A', '12/12/2012', '12/12/2014')
                        ,('B', '05/08/2006', '07/11/2009')
```

Query:

```
SELECT t.name, YEAR(DATEADD(year,n.number, t.startdate)) AS Year
FROM #test t,
(SELECT number
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE [type] = 'P') n
WHERE startdate <= DATEADD(year,n.number, t.startdate)
AND enddate >= DATEADD(year,n.number, t.startdate)
```

Result:

```
name    Year
A       2012
A       2013
A       2014
B       2006
B       2007
B       2008
B       2009
```